# Does cast away const of *this cause undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, constants, undefined-behavior

The following code compiles. It seems to run fine.

But would it cause any undefined behavior?

I want to cast away the const of `*this`.

This is for allowing a `const my_iterator` to mutate the data it points at.

Test:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const int x) : x_(x) {}
    void set_x(int x) { x_ = x; }
    void set_x2(const int x) const {
        const_cast<A&>(*this).set_x(x);
    }
    int x_;
};

int main() {
    A a(10);
    a.set_x2(100);
}
```

Comment: In this case, this is UB.  But you could declare `mutable int x_;`.  Then you can modify it even if the object itself is const, without casting away constness.

Comment: Why `set_x2` has to be `const`? Your example works fine without added `constness` and `const_cast`

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't believe this is UB, as `a` is non-const to begin with

Comment: `mutable` is meh in the view of multi-threading. Why is your method `const` to begin with if it modifies members?

Comment: @Justin You're right.  But if `a` was const, it would be UB.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I don't know. Somehow a `const std::vector<int>::iterator` allows modifying the value it points at. So I want to follow that convention for `T* const`.

Comment: @Rzu The iterator being `const` does not imply the thing it points to is `const`. It's like in `const` pointer vs pointer to `const` data. Seems like you are confusing the two.

Comment: @Rzu Let's imagine that inside the `std::vector<int>::iterator`, you have a `int* internalIterator;`. If you had a `const std::vector<int>::iterator`, that `const` only applies on the top level, so the `internalIterator` member would be a `int* const internalIterator`, not a `int const* const internalIterator`

Comment: The equivalent C code would be perfectly defined because the original object is not const. I don't know about C++, but there's a great deal of correspondence between the 2 langs.

Comment: @PSkocik C and C++ are completely different languages, with different semantics. Comments like yours are not really helpful.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I have to disagree with you. PSkocik's comment *is* helpful. Even though C and C++ are distinct languages, there *are* a lot of similarities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is not undefined behavior because `a` is not `const`. However, if `a` were `const`, it would be:

```
int main() {
    const A a(10);
    a.set_x2(100);
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer, if the original `*this` is const, then it is undefined. therefore, it is on you to know what you can and can't `const_cast`

Comment: It's the correct answer to the question as stated, but I'm quite sure that was not the question OP should be asking themselves to begin with.

Comment: agreed, there's only a few valid uses of `mutable` and even less for `const_cast`

Comment: The new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50164588/const-span-and-iterator-trouble