# const, span, and iterator trouble

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I try to write an iterator that iterates over a container by index. 
A `It` and a `const It` both allow changing the content of the container. 
A `Const_it` and a `const Const_it` both forbid changing the content of the container.

After that, I try to write a `span<T>` over a container.
For a type `T` that is not const, both `const span<T>` and `span<T>` allows changing the content of the container. 
Both `const span<const T>` and `span<const T>` forbid changing the content of the container.

The code does not compile because:

```
    // *this is const within a const method
    // But It<self_type> requires a non-const *this here.
    // So the code does not compile
    It<self_type> begin() const { return It<self_type>(*this, 0); }
```

If I make the constructor of `It` to accept a `const` container, it doesn't look right because the iterator can modify the content of the container.

If I get rid of the const of the method, then for a non-const type T, a `const span<T>` cannot modify the container.

`It` inherits from `Const_it` to allow implicit conversion from `It` to `Const_it` during template instantiation.

I use a pointer instead of a reference to in the iterators (`const C* container_;`) for allowing assigning one iterator to another iterator.

I suspect something is very wrong here because I even think about:

[Does cast away const of *this cause undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163959/does-cast-away-const-of-this-cause-undefined-behavior)

But I don't know how to fix it.

Test:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

template<typename C>
class Const_it {
    typedef Const_it<C> self_type;
public:
    Const_it(const C& container, const int ix)
            : container_(&container), ix_(ix) {}
    self_type& operator++() {
        ++ix_;
        return *this;
    }

    const int& operator*() const {
        return ref_a()[ix_];
    }

    bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) const {
        return ix_ != rhs.ix_;
    }

protected:
    const C& ref_a() const { return *container_; }
    const C* container_;
    int ix_;
};

template<typename C>
class It : public Const_it<C> {
    typedef Const_it<C> Base;
    typedef It<C> self_type;
public:
    //It(const C& container.
    It(C& container, const int ix)
            : Base::Const_it(container, ix) {}
    self_type& operator++() {
        ++ix_;
        return *this;
    }

    int& operator*() const {
        return mutable_a()[ix_];
    }

private:
    C& mutable_a() const { return const_cast<C&>(ref_a()); }
    using Base::ref_a;
    using Base::container_;
    using Base::ix_;
};


template <typename V>
class span {
    typedef span<V> self_type;
public:
    explicit span(V& v) : v_(v) {}
    It<self_type> begin() { return It<self_type>(*this, 0); }
    // *this is const within a const method
    // But It<self_type> requires a non-const *this here.
    // So the code does not compile
    It<self_type> begin() const { return It<self_type>(*this, 0); }
    It<self_type> end() { return It<self_type>(*this, v_.size()); }
    It<self_type> end() const { return It<self_type>(*this, v_.size()); }

    int& operator[](const int ix) {return v_[ix];}
    const int& operator[](const int ix) const {return v_[ix];}
private:
    V& v_;
};


int main() {
    typedef std::vector<int> V;
    V v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
    std::cout << v.size() << "\n";
    const span<V> s(v);
    for (auto&& x : s) {
        x = 4;
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid undefined behavior, or are you requiring the user to be aware when they are using `It` in an undefined behavior fashion?

Comment: If you want it to compile, you can use const_cast. For example : `It<self_type> begin() const { return It<self_type>(*const_cast<span*>(this), 0); }`

Comment: I want to avoid undefined behavior when the user uses `span<T>`, and `const span<T>` for a type T that may be const.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main notes to be said to make this work. First:

> If I make the constructor of It to accept a const container, it doesn't look right because the iterator can modify the content of the container.

Not really, because `C` in your `template<typename C> class It` is **not** the actual container, but the `span<V>`. In other words, take a look at:

```
It<self_type> begin() const { return It<self_type>(*this, 0); }
```

Here `self_type` means `const span<V>`, therefore you are returning a `It<const span<V>>`. Thus, your iterator can do whatever can be done with a `const span` -- but the container is still non-`const`. The variable name `container_` is not fortunate, then.

> For a type `T` that is not `const`, both `const span<T>` and `span<T>` allows changing the content of the container. Both `const span<const T>` and `span<const T>` forbid changing the content of the container.

In addition, since you want that `const span` is allowed to modify the contents, then what you should write inside `span` itself is (note the `const`):

```
int& operator[](const int ix) const {return v_[ix];}
// Removing the other `const` version:
// const int& operator[](const int ix) const {return v_[ix];}
```

With those two bits clarified, you can then construct a working example. Here is one based from your code and simplified to solve the issue at hand:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename S>
class It {
    typedef It<S> self_type;
    const S& span_;
    int ix_;

public:
    It(const S& span, const int ix)
        : span_(span), ix_(ix) {}

    self_type& operator++() {
        ++ix_;
        return *this;
    }

    int& operator*() const {
        return span_[ix_];
    }

    bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) const {
        return &span_ != &rhs.span_ or ix_ != rhs.ix_;
    }
};

template <typename V>
class span {
    typedef span<V> self_type;
public:
    explicit span(V& v) : v_(v) {}
    It<self_type> begin() const { return It<self_type>(*this, 0); }
    It<self_type> end() const { return It<self_type>(*this, v_.size()); }

    int& operator[](const int ix) const {return v_[ix];}
private:
    V& v_;
};

int main() {
    typedef std::vector<int> V;
    V v(10);
    const span<V> s(v);
    for (auto&& x : s) {
        x = 4;
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }
}
```

Take a look as well at the corrected implementation of `operator!=` and at the fact that there is no need for the non-`const` version of `begin()` and `end()`. You can also throw there a `cbegin()` and `cend()`. Then you have to work on adding back the const iterator cases.

---

By the way, in case it saves some confusion for anybody: in the near future, [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) ([proposed for C++20](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0122r6.pdf)) might be added; and it will be just a `(pointer-to-first-element, index)` pair -- rather than your `(pointer-to-container, index)` version.

In other words, as its template parameter, it will take the elements' type, rather than a container:

```
span<std::vector<int>> s(v);
// vs
std::span<int> s(v);
```

This allows consumers of `std::span` to avoid knowing about which container is behind the scenes (or even no container: a contiguous memory area or an array).

Finally, you may want to take a look at [GSL's implementation of `std::span`](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span) to get some inspiration on how to fully implement it (including the second template parameter about the extent).

Comment: I don't know that a const method can return a non-const reference: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#return-const-ref-from-const-memfn

Comment: So a top level const for an object doesn't mean absolutely nothing can be changed for the object. It just means the object can only be changed according to the const-version of the class.

Comment: Without const-overloading a method, both a const object and non-const object will use the same method if the method is const.

Answer (score 0):

After studying Acorn's solution, I found another fix.

This allows using the same iterator template for both a `std::vector<T>` and a `span`.

The two cases are different. 
For a non-const type `T`, a `const std::vector<T>` forbids changing its element. A `const span<T>` allows changing its elements.

The main difference is `It<const self_type>(*this, 0);` in the `span` class and `S& span_;` instead of `const S& span_;` in the `It` class.

Fix:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename S>
class It {
    typedef It<S> self_type;
public:
    It(S& span, const int ix)
            : span_(span), ix_(ix) {}

    self_type& operator++() {
        ++ix_;
        return *this;
    }

    int& operator*() const {
        return span_[ix_];
    }

    bool operator!=(const self_type& rhs) const {
        return &span_ != &rhs.span_ or ix_ != rhs.ix_;
    }

private:
    S& span_;
    int ix_;
};

template<typename V>
class span {
    typedef span<V> self_type;
public:
    explicit span(V& v) : v_(v) {}

    It<const self_type> begin() const {
        return It<const self_type>(*this, 0);
    }

    It<const self_type> end() const {
        return It<const self_type>(*this, v_.size());
    }

    int& operator[](const int ix) const { return v_[ix]; }

private:
    V& v_;
};

int main() {
    // Test adding iterator to a span
    typedef std::vector<int> V;
    V v(10);
    const span<V> s(v);
    for (auto&& x : s) {
        x = 4;
        std::cout << x << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    // Test adding iterator to a std::vector
    const It<V> begin(v, 0);
    const It<V> end(v, v.size());

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        *it = 10;
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: The check for equality `&span_ != &rhs.span_` is costly if `span_` is actually a `std::vector<T>`. Maybe it is ok if only check if `span_` and `&rhs.span_` actually refers to the same address in memory and have the same size? But that may cause other problem as well... Maybe I can add an assertion for that to forbid comparing Iterators over two different containers.

Comment: Another problem is the type conversion from an iterator produced by begin() method of a span for mutable access to an iterator produced by begin() method of a span for immutable access.